# ASP MVC API IEnumerable JSON array missing key name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a ASP MVC API Controller that returns a IEnumerable array as JSON
but I do not get the key name for the array all I get is

```
[1]
0:  {
$id: "1"
id: 1
itemid: "Flame 19#Bag Acosta Produce Ctn A"
descrip: "Flame grape very suite on Carton Box"
createdate: "2013-11-17T06:26:50.047"
/...
```

I need the key for inventory like below,

```
inventory:[1]
0:  {
$id: "1"
id: 1
itemid: "Flame 19#Bag Acosta Produce Ctn A"
descrip: "Flame grape very suite on Carton Box"
createdate: "2013-11-17T06:26:50.047"
/...
```

Code

```
public class DtoController : ApiController
{
    private ProduceServiceContext db = new ProduceServiceContext();

    public IEnumerable<InventoryDTO> MapInventories()
    {
        return from i in db.Inventories
        select new InventoryDTO() { id = i.InventoryId, createdate = i.CreateDate ?? DateTime.MinValue, descrip = i.Descriptions,
            itemid = i.ItemDetail, gtin = i.GTIN, lastcost = i.LastCost
/...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return new { inventory = from i in db.Inventories
        select new InventoryDTO() { id = i.InventoryId, createdate = i.CreateDate ?? DateTime.MinValue, descrip = i.Descriptions,
            itemid = i.ItemDetail, gtin = i.GTIN, lastcost = i.LastCost };
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but I got this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProduceService.Models.InventoryDTO>

Comment: Oops, my mistake. You should just make a class like pubic class InventoryData { public IEnumerable<InventoryDTO> Inventory { get; set; } } and change your method for returning this type: return new InventoryData { Inventory = ... };